# Proper If-Else Syntax

Tags: php, if-statement

If the sql insertion succeeds, then it will display "Success". If there is an error, then it will display "Name is taken". The problem is that it displays both when there is an error.

My php code is below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO event_calendar (name, detail, place, date, time) VALUES ('$name', '$detail', '$place', '$date', '$time')";

if($sql){ 

    echo "<div>";
    echo "<p> Success </p>";

    }           
    echo '<p>Name is taken</p>';
}
?>
```

How do I stop both from being displayed? Any ideas?

Comment: is the question are not clear? how come I got -1 ?

Comment: First you need to check if name or any other unique field is already in database. You can also do SQL queries to first check then insert as a single query. The result in the second case can be processed as if `affected_rows` then.... Anyway, considering your code above, you're most likely not going to understand what I'm saying and as you haven't really posted your actual attempt at this, there's nothing to help on except to do the work for you :)

Comment: Do you ever even execute your SQL or are you just making an if comparsion based on the string of your SQL? I have a feeling that you have tried to achieve too ambitious goals too soon. Before trying to handle database interaction learn basic programming from w3schools or code academy for example.

Comment: Hello guys, I already made my column name such as name and detail as a UNIQUE. Maybe you're right. All i need is SQL injection probably. I missed that part only I guess. Thanks @s3ib for explanation, actually I'm still a new beginner for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about if else constructs: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Also SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

Since "Name is taken" is not in an else block it will get executed everytime.
if($sql){

```
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<p> Success </p>";

    }else{           
    echo '<p>Name is taken</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use that method, it doesn't work too..

Comment: http://phptrycatch.blogspot.com/ A "Try/Catch" block would be my next suggestion. This attempts to execute a line of code( in the 'try' block ) and if there is an exception thrown it does whatever is in the catch block

Comment: thanks! thats a good method :)